# Hibernate - How to insert N new rows with unique timestamps as id (DB2)

Tags: hibernate, db2

For historic reasons the id of this table as a unique timestamp.

I need to insert a batch of N rows at once. DB2 has a TIMESTAMP(GENERATE_UNIQUE) function which can handle this. But is there a way to do it from Java/Hibernate while enforcing the timestamp uniqueness code? The timestamp is a LocalDateTime in Java. The code runs on two instances with 10 threads each. So just generating the LocalDataTime's manually might cause some concurrency issues.

```
create table BUSINESS
(
    BUSINESS_ID    TIMESTAMP(6) not null,
    ...
);

create unique index BPMIC055
    on BUSINESS (BUSINESS_ID);
```

Comment: Try a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger with the `TIMESTAMP(GENERATE_UNIQUE)` expression.